# How to get the limit cycle of a nonlinear oscillator using Shooting Method?

Tags: computational-physics, oscillators, non-linear-systems, complex-systems

I am trying to find the limit cycle of a nonlinear oscillator like a duffing or Van-der-Pol oscillator directly using the shooting method. I know how to use the Shooting method to solve a Boundary Value Problem. But I cannot apply the same to an initial value problem like finding the limit cycle of a nonlinear oscillator. I read some papers which discussed the required approach, but I didn't understand them because no examples were discussed. I would have shared them here, but they are not open access.

The whole point of using the Shooting method here is to get the limit cycle efficiently without much computation compared to integrating over the entire time interval.

Comment: I understand it like this,- change randomly initial values $\ddot x_0, \dot x_0, x_0$ of Van der Pol oscillator, then see where trajectory converges and this will be your limit cycle. But I may get it wrong. Also I'm not sure is this the best place of looking the answer, it maybe more suitable to math.stackexchange as it is about numerical solving methods.

Comment: *I read some papers which discussed the required approach....I would have shared them here, but they are not open access.* You can still provide article titles & authors, DOIs, etc, even when the articles are not open access.